# How to create a custom global exception handler for filters in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, spring-security

Is there a way to custom a handler to deal with Spring Security exception and custom exception in Spring Security filters? I need a formatted response with error infomation sent to front end.

Comment: may be check this out, it might help https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/exception-handling-in-spring-security

Comment: @Avi thanks，it only tells the springsecurity exception but custom one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement a custom global exception handler by adding a filter:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class GlobalExceptionFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        mapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), new ErrorInfo("something bad happened"));
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        response.getWriter().close();
        response.getWriter().flush();
    }  
}
```

The error information sent to the frontend would be contained in the *ErrorInfo* class:

```
public class ErrorInfo {

    // some custom fields as you wish

    public ErrorInfo(String error) {
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see above, it's important to let the filter execute before all other filters by adding the [@Order](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) annotation with [HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html#HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) as value. If there are some other filters with the same order, you have to increase their order (for example by replacing *Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE* with *Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1*) to make them execute after our exception handling filter.

Also, you have to ensure that your filter gets executed before the Spring Security filter chain. Thus, you need to change the order of the Spring Security filter-chain by setting the *security.filter-order* property in *application.properties* to some value higher than the order of our GlobalExceptionFilter:

```
security.filter-order=0
```

When an exception happens somewhere in our filter-chain, the exception will be caught by the *GlobalExceptionFilter* which in turn creates an *ErrorInfo* object containing information about the error and serializes it using a [Jackson ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html). Finally, the response is sent to the client with a given *HTTP status*.

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot. And one more question why set the exception filter highest order? In my mind, it should be lowest. I am confused about order

Comment: I think the exception filter should be the last one in the chain. Then it can catch all exceptions

Comment: I also find the name confusing. If you take a look at the value of this integer constant you will see that it has a value of Integer.MIN_VALUE. In fact, a filter with a lower order has higher priority than a filter with a higher order. Theay are "sorted" in ascending order. Probably the creators gave it this name to emphasize the higher priority (precedence) which is given to a bean with lower order value..

Comment: @wl.GIG it must go before all other filters because this is the first filter in the chain, then it forwards the request to the next filter and each filter is forwarding it also to the next filter. After a filter finishes its execution, the control flow is returned to the filter before him, so the control flow at the end is returned  to the first filter in the chain.

Comment: I got it. Thanks